# In ClojureScript, What is the difference between `int?` and `integer?` and `number?`?

Tags: clojurescript

In ClojureScript,
What is the difference between `int?` and `integer?` and `number?` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number?` does what is equivalent to `typeof x === 'number'` in JS.

`integer?` does that, plus also checks if it's not a NaN, not an Infinity, and has no fraction part (i.e. a regular integer value, not a float).

`int?` is a disjunction of the checks for `integer?`, an instance of `goog.math.Integer`, and an instance of `goog.math.Long`.

The source code of all of the functions is very straightforward - I definitely recommend checking it out.